# (Locally) sym., homogenous spaces and space forms

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, differential-geometry, manifolds, differential-topology

We had some definitions of particular types of Riemannian manifolds in our lecture

1.) Locally symmetric spaces. They were Riemannian manifolds with the property that $\nabla R=0$ everywhere.

2.) Symmetric spaces. They were path-conn. Riemannian manifolds such that there is for each $p \in M$ a global isometry $f_p: M \rightarrow M$ such that $f(\gamma(t)) = f(\gamma(-t))$ for all geodesics $\gamma: (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon) \rightarrow M$ satisfying $\gamma(0)=p$ and $Df_p(p) = -id.$

3.) Homogenous spaces. They were maps admitting for every $p,q\in M$ a global isometry $\phi_{p,q}: M \rightarrow M$ such that $\phi(p)=q$

4.) Finally, we introduced space-forms as complete connected Riemannian manifolds of const. curvature.

Now, to enhance my understanding of all these spaces, I wanted to get the relations between these spaces right.

So, I found out that any symm. space is homogenous and every symm. space is locally symmetric. Furthermore, any symm. space is complete and path.-connected so i.e. a space form.

Now, I have basically three questions that I could not really answer

1.) Is there a way to compare homogenous, loc. symm. spaces and space forms, too?

2.) Which of these spaces have constant sectional curvature everywhere? By the global isometry property I guess it holds for hom., symm. spaces and space forms, but I don't know if this is also true for loc. symm. spaces?

3.) Are there easy(!) examples of spaces that are one but not the other? ( Naming them woud be totally sufficient, I would try to figure it out by myself why they are examples)

Comment: This is a monstrously huge question. Basically you are asking for an entire course in one stackexchange answer. You might get a lot more mileage by breaking this into one small answerable question at a time.

Comment: @LeeMosher you think I should ask all three questions separately? Actually I refrained from doing so, cause I thought that $1$ can be answered in one sentence, as either you can say that one of them is a subset of another one or not. $2$ is basically a yes, no question, because either loc. symm. spaces have constant sectional curvature or not and in $3$ I asked only for the examples (without any details). Furthermore, all questions are all highly related but if you still think that a splitting is appropriate, please leave me a comment and I will do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need examples. The archetypal example of **locally symmetric but non homogeneous** space is a compact quotient of the unit disk. Namely, a compact Riemannian surface with its canonical metric also called hyperbolic Riemann surfaces. Here you have more details: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_surface

So usually the difference between locally symmetric and symmetric is related to the topology or the lack of completeness.

The archetypal examples of **homogeneous but not locally symmetric** space are given by a Lie group endowed by a so called left invariant metric (some of them are of course symmetric but in general they are not). Between them my favorite one is the Heisenberg group https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_group endowed with a left invariant metric.

The archetypal example of **symmetric space that is not a space form** is the complex plane $\mathbb{C}P^2$ endowed with its Fubini-Study metric.

If you want more information I can edit my answer and add more details.

Comment: mhmm, I am wondering why a symmetric space that is not a space form even exists. According to my reasoning any symmertric space is complete and path-connected so i.e. a space form?

Comment: but thank you for your examples, I think I this sufficiently answers question 1 and 3. Do you you also know the answer to question 2.)

Comment: As I wrote the complex projective $\mathbb{C}P^2$ endowed with the Fubini-Study metric is a symmetric space but has not constant sectional curvature: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini%E2%80%93Study_metric .  As far as I see this answer question (2), in the sense that show you the existence of a homogeneous spaces, even symmetric whose sectional curvature is not constant.

Comment: ah, thanks. good to know.

Comment: since Lee Mosher suggested that this question is already pretty big, I started a new related question that you are probably able to answer, too. http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1332945/theorema-egregrium-violated-in-dimension-n-ge-4